# Object reference not set to an instance of an object FiftyOne.Foundation.PreApplicationStart.Start()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

[image: Object reference not set to an instance of an object FiftyOne.Foundation.PreApplicationStart.Start()]

Hi, 
I am suddenly getting the above depicted error message while running my MVC application! Could anyone help ,please?

Comment: Provide your code please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fixed it. Just need to remove everything in bin folder and run again! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have not used the keyword **NEW**
E.G.

Dim myBox As New PictureBox

The reference here is **myBox**

Hopefully this heelps. :-)

Regards,

John O.